# If statement not working properly in form validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I've would like to make a really simple form validation is JS.

I've created a function with if statements inside,while everything is ok it should display nothing and when something is not right (number in a name input for e.g)
a message under a certain input should be displayed.Right now it sometimes work,sometimes not.

If anybody could look at my code and tell me what's wrong would be really helpful

[Here's my live version](https://atomix94.github.io/Send-Form.github.io/)

[Here's the code](https://github.com/atomix94/Send-Form.github.io/commit/4a8e86befb5fdde5e321f5ed17b6b41d8656f929)

Comment: Code should be posted **here**, not linked.

Comment: Please post your code in a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

You are using `name="name-surname"` twice (in two different `input` tags), which prevents the values to be sent properly. Use the same values for `name`  as the values for the `ID`s